# Typescript lookup types with return type

Tags: typescript

How can I tell typescript what is return type based on a key name provided as param:

```
type A = string
type B = number

type Data = {
    a: A,
    b: B
}

const getProp = (data: Data, key: keyof Data) => {
    return data[key]
}

const myData: Data = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 123
}

// Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

        ^  
const result: string = getProp(myData, 'a')
```

I know that I am taking prop `a` so expected return type is string.
How can I make it work please?
[playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDOwBOBLAdgcwFCkigCEEpMBXAWwCMJVd9xoARAQ2FdIG9co%20pWALlgAaXv2rCiuAL4MAxgHtMKKNgjAACqkVhSACgAm7IVDYcRUANYQQwmyEUAzMyYCUCAHxQe-KKg1yVEwoYw4AbQcAXVkFZVVKEHNTZO5xPlMAcidFRUyxP0koAEYAJgBmWNwlFWB-CCRyABtgYRQMHFJ1LR0wfUTky0zWTLdcIA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a generic type:

```js
const getProp = <K extends keyof Data>(data: Data, key: K): Data[K] => {
    return data[key]
}
```

This works because `K` can be inferred at the call-site to be the string literal type `'a'` (which does extend `keyof Data`), and then the return type `Data[K]` is `Data['a']`, which is `string`.

Comment: Amazing! I was actually positively surprised that in the function call I didn't need to specify function declaration for typescript to understand return type. Thank you!